# Riemann tensor component always zero?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following property of the Riemannian curvature tensor:
$$ R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd} $$ so... is this true for any manifold??
$$ R_{aacd}=-R_{aacd} $$
$$ R_{aacd}+R_{aacd}=0 $$
$$ 2R_{aacd}=0 $$
$$ R_{aacd}=0 $$

Comment: Yes, in this form, $R\in S^2(\Lambda^2T^*M)$. Which means that also $R_{abcc}=0$ and $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$.

Comment: OMG!!! :DD That's incredible! Sooo much simplification.... Oh wow...

Comment: So why don't people just write $R_{aacd}=0$ and $R_{abcc}=0$ instead of $R_{abcd}=−R_{bacd}$ ? :)

Comment: Because anti-symmetry involves more than only a zero diagonal.

Comment: @LutzL You should write this as an answer. Otherwise it looks like this question is unanswered.

Comment: @DanielMahler: Ok, comments expanded as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting comments:

The curvature tensor with all lower indices, i.e., in its completely covariant form, is in the space $R∈S^2(Λ^2T^∗M)$. Which means that it is anti-symmetric (separately) in the first and second pair of indices and symmetric between those pairs as groups. Thus

- $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$ which implies $R_{aacd}=0$ and for every fixed pair $cd$ the variation of entries $ab$ forms an anti-symmetric matrix.
- the same is true for the second pair of indices, $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$ and $R_{abcc}=0$,
- which would also follow from the symmetry property $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ for the group of pairs since $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}=-R_{dcab}=-R_{abdc}$.

The full stage four tensor can have $n^4$ components. $Λ^2T^∗M$ has $m=\frac12 n(n-1)$ different coordinates and the symmetric space over it $\frac12 m(m+1)=\frac18n(n-1)(n(n-1)+2)\simeq \frac18 n^4$ different coordinates, so there is lots of dependencies between the components of the tensor.